# Extending a quasi-isometry of a neutered hyperbolic space

Tags: metric-spaces, hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-group-theory, gromov-hyperbolic-spaces

Suppose $\phi : B \to B$ is a quasi-isometry of a neutered space $B$ (so $B$ is obtained by removing a collection of disjoint open horoballs from $\mathbb{H}^n$, and the metric $d_B$ on $B$ is the path metric induced by the hyperbolic metric $d_\mathbb{H}$). Is it possible to extend $\phi$ to a quasi-isometry on $\mathbb{H}^n$? That is, does there exist a quasi-isometry $\hat\phi : \mathbb{H}^n \to \mathbb{H}^n$ such that $\hat\phi \vert_B = \phi$?

I have some ideas for how to define $\hat\phi$ (assuming the answer to my question is yes), but I have some concerns which leads me to think that maybe the answer to my question is no. If such an extension exists, then it seems to imply that the quasi-isometry $\phi$ of $(B,d_B)$ is also a quasi-isometry (with probably different QI constants) of $(B,d_\mathbb{H})$. To my intuition however, this seems unlikely. While we do know that $d_\mathbb{H}(p,q) \le d_B(p,q)$ for points $p,q \in B$, I do not know of a sufficiently strong (e.g. coarse Lipschitz) inequality going the other direction. So I don't see much reason to believe that $\phi : (B,d_\mathbb{H}) \to (B,d_\mathbb{H})$ will be a quasi-isometry.

If I am right that $\phi$ cannot be directly extended, then is there any other natural way to construct a quasi-isometry of $\mathbb{H}^n$ from $\phi$?

Comment: Try removing a horoball in $\mathbb{H}^2$ and comparing the metrics on the boundary horocyle.

Comment: In the upper-half plane model, consider the horocycle $y=y_0$. The metric $d_{\mathbb{H}}$ on the horocycle depends on $y_0$, but $d_B$ does not. So I guess it is hopeless to get any sufficient, uniform relation between the two metrics?

Comment: What book/paper are you reading?

Comment: @MoisheKohan This question comes my research, not any particular reading.

Comment: That strange, since earlier you were reading a book (“Geometric Group Theory”) which contains an answer to the posted question.

Comment: Oh goodness, that's embarrassing. You're right, I now see the result in that book, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to see that it isn't always possible to build such an extension, at least in $\Bbb{H}^2$. Take a once-cusped finite volume hyperbolic surface $S$, and cut off the cusp with a horosphere, leaving a compact surface with boundary. The universal cover of this cut-off surface is a neutered space $X$ in $\Bbb{H}^2$, which is given the path metric $d_X$.

The fundamental group of $S$ is free, and it acts by cocompactly and by isometries on $(X, d_X)$. So Svarc-Milnor tells you that $(X, d_X)$ is quasi-isometric to a tree. The boundary at infinity of this tree is a Cantor set, which maps (non-injectively) into the ideal boundary of hyperbolic space.

Any quasi-isometry of $(X, d_X)$ which extends to a quasi-isometry of $\Bbb{H}^2$ has to preserve the cyclic order on the ideal boundary of $\Bbb{H}^2$. But, you can find plenty of quasi-isometries of trees that don't do this.

This argument is pretty special to $\Bbb{H}^2$. I am not actually sure what should happen in higher dimensions, since you may be able to argue in those cases that a quasi-isometry of the neutered space must permute the horospheres (although maybe not). [Edit: see YCor's comment below for the answer to this question.]

Comment: You seem to implicitly assume that $X$ has finite volume, so that removing the (finitely many) cusps yields a compact core.

Comment: Conversely in negatively curved symmetric spaces $Y$ of dimension $>2$, self-QIs of neutered spaces $X\subset Y$  extend to the whole symmetric space. This is due to Richard Schwartz (Publ IHES 1995) http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1995__82__133_0/ See Step 3 therein. Hence the OP's question has a positive answer for $n\ge 3$ and negative for $n=2$.

Comment: Two good points. thanks, edited.

Comment: @YCor Thank you!